# Pass parameter to callback query in pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I've a bot that performs a set of actions and takes date as input at a particular point. Bot is made using [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) and I'm using this [library](https://github.com/artembakhanov/python-telegram-bot-calendar) for date input. Do I have to create a class and temporarily store data there during the flow? or is there a simpler way. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
def process_transaction_name_input(message):
    # I need to access this message argument in the below callback function
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Great! The transaction name is *{message.text}*. Let\'s choose a date for the transaction.',
                     parse_mode='Markdown')
    calendar, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar(max_date=date.today()).build()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f"Select {LSTEP[step]}",
                     reply_markup=calendar)
    

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=DetailedTelegramCalendar.func())
def cal(c):
    result, key, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar(max_date=date.today(), current_date=date.today()).process(c.data)
    if not result and key:
        bot.edit_message_text(f"Select {LSTEP[step]}",
                              c.message.chat.id,
                              c.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=key)
    elif result:
        bot.edit_message_text(f"You selected {result}",
                              c.message.chat.id,
                              c.message.message_id)
        process_transaction_category_input(c.message)
        # access previous method argument here 
        # and pass as process_transaction_category_input(c.message, argument)
```